# SVG Cross Browser (Firefox) Issues

Tags: firefox, svg, cross-browser

I tried to adapt a codepen thing for waves with svgs. 
Works just fine in Chrome, Safari and Edge, but not in Firefox (and IE, but I don't care too much about that). 
I suspect some Syntax problem with the svg. The animation works just fine, but the svgs are not displayed correctly. In Firefox it's just a straight line instead of waves. 
Anyone out there, that has an idea about that?
Thanks a lot in advance.

```css
.waves {
    width: 100%;
    height: 7em;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f6f9fc;
}

.wave
{
 width:calc( 100% + 4em );
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 left:-2em;
 background:bottom center repeat-x;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 animation-timing-function:linear;
}


/* Individual wave layers */

.wave_1
{
  animation-name:wave_1;
  animation-duration:3400ms;
  animation-delay:-1200ms;
  z-index:2;
  opacity: 1;
  background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="2000" viewBox="0 0 600 2000"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#fff" d="M600 2000c-100.8 0-141.6-39.892-240-39.892S98.4 2000 0 2000V0h6000v2000z"/></svg>');
  background-position:bottom left;
  background-color: #e0e7f1;
  top: -3em;
}
.wave_2
{
  z-index:1;
  opacity: 1;
  background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="2000" viewBox="0 0 600 2000"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#e0e7f1" d="M600 2000c-100.8 0-141.6-39.892-240-39.892S98.4 2000 0 2000V0h6000v2000z"/></svg>');
  background-position:bottom left;
  background-color: #245aa6;
  top: 0em;
}


@keyframes wave_1
{
 from { transform: rotate(0deg)   translatey(-0.61em) rotate(0deg)    ; }
 to   { transform: rotate(360deg) translatey(-0.61em) rotate(-360deg) ; }
}
```

```html
 <div class="waves">
    <div class="wave wave_1"></div>
   <div class="wave wave_2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your URLs are invalid # is the start of a fragment identifier and must be encoded as %23

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you so much! I knew I was being blind...